# Strangely VS keep giving me a squiggly line - how to remove for importing python files

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio

programm works fine and runns but i just get annoyed by the yellow line grr

[image: as you can see these lines are annoying]

Comment: Did you try closing and reopening vscode

Comment: If you hover over the squiggle, what does the editor tell you?